Paginated Data, Should I keep it as state of the screen or only internal state to recycler view adapter?
How to manage paginated data in a StateFlow for a RecyclerView?
Should I store only the last fetched page in the StateFlow and accumulate data in the adapter, or should I store the entire dataset in the StateFlow?
I tried to store the new page fetched from remote source in StateFlow and incrememnt the data in the adapter,
But I don't know whether we follow best practice of having the full screen state at any point of time?
